# Probability of getting a ball from different bags knowing the total number of balls

Tags: probability

Let's say we have 4 bags. Each bags contain an unknown number of balls. We know the total number of balls, let's call it n.

What would be the most efficient algorithm to get balls and stop when the aggregated probability of the ball we have in hand is equal to the uniform probability as if all the balls were in the same bag, so 1/n?

Comment: What is the "aggregated probability of the ball we have in hand"?

Comment: Probably not the best way to express it. Did it on my cell. What I mean by that is the probability given all the events that took place to have that ball in hand. Let's say we have two bags, one with 4 balls and one with 6. The probability of choosing ball 6 of bag 2 is 1/2*1/6. If we then put back the ball and pick another one, Let's say we pick ball 1 of bag 1. Its probability is 1/2*1/4. You have ball 1 of bag 1 but we drew ball 6 of bag 2 just before. What is the probability (aggregated probability for lack of a better term) to get those two one after the other.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to calculate the (non-uniform) probabilites?  For that I'd think you need to know the number in each bag.  Or are you asking for a procedure to simulate the case of all balls in the same bag?

Comment: It would be the later. Simulate the case of all balls in the same bag.